# How to make a flat array with a specific sequence?

Tags: javascript

I have a nested array, but I need to make a flat array from this array, but so that everything goes one by one

```
const data = [
  {
    titles: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Title 01",
        subtitles: [
          {
            id: 2,
            name: "Subtitle 01",
            title_id: 1,
            content: [
              {
                id: 3,
                name: "Content 01",
                subtitle_id: 2,
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: "Title 01",
        subtitles: [
          {
            id: 5,
            name: "Subtitle 01",
            title_id: 4,
            content: [
              {
                id: 6,
                name: "Content 01",
                subtitle_id: 5,
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

Need

```
const flatArr = [
  {
    titles01: {
      name: "Title 01",
      id: 1,
    },
    sutitles01: {
      name: "Subtitle 01",
      id: 2,
      title_id: 1,
    },
    content01: {
      id: 3,
      name: "Content 01",
      subtitle_id: 2,
    },
    titles02: {
      name: "Title 02",
      id: 4,
    },
    sutitles02: {
      name: "Subtitle 02",
      id: 5,
      title_id: 4,
    },
    content02: {
      id: 6,
      name: "Content 02",
      subtitle_id: 5,
    },
  },
]
```

That is, so that the array is flat and everything goes one by one, start with title01, then subtitle01, then content01, then title02, then sibtitle02, then content02, so that there is such a hierarchy, is this even possible? Unfortunately, I don't have any code examples because nothing worked...

Comment: Your sample output doesn't have `title01`, etc. Is that a mistake?

Comment: @NickParsons title01 - title

Comment: Your input has only 01, not 02, yet your output has 02. What if you have a duplicate `name` that ends with "dog", or "-", then what?

Comment: Why is your output an array, when it only has one element? What is the purpose of that? Didn't you mean to have an array with multiple objects!? Or else just a plain object (not an array)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
    let titles = {}
data.forEach((item, key) => {
  item.titles.forEach(title => {
    if (title.id < 10) {

      titles = {
        ...titles,
        ['titles0' + title.id]: {name: title.name, id: title.id}
      }

    } else {
      titles = {
        ...titles,
        ['titles' + title.id]: {name: title.name, id: title.id}
      }
    }

    title.subtitles.forEach(subtitle => {
      if (title.id < 10) {
        titles = {
          ...titles, ['subtitles0' + subtitle.id]: {
            id: subtitle.id,
            name: subtitle.name,
            title_id: subtitle.title_id,
          }
        }
      } else {
        titles = {
          ...titles, ['subtitles' + subtitle.id]: {
            id: subtitle.id,
            name: subtitle.name,
            title_id: subtitle.title_id,
          }
        }
      }

      subtitle.content.forEach(content => {
        if (title.id < 10) {
          titles = {
            ...titles,
            ['content0' + content.id]:
              {
                name: content.name,
                id: content.id,
                subtitle_id: content.subtitle_id
              }
          }
        } else {
          titles = {
            ...titles,
            ['content' + content.id]:
              {
                name: content.name,
                id: content.id,
                subtitle_id: content.subtitle_id
              }
          }
        }
      })
    })

  })
})

console.log('flatArr', [titles])
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a function that can give you desired result as above**

```
const transformArray = (data) => {
  return data.reduce((result, topLevelItem, index) => {

    const titlesKey = `titles${index + 1}`;
    const subtitlesKey = `subtitles${index + 1}`;
    const contentKey = `content${index + 1}`;

    result[titlesKey] = {
      name: topLevelItem.titles[0].name,
      id: topLevelItem.titles[0].id,
    };

    result[subtitlesKey] = {
      name: topLevelItem.titles[0].subtitles[0].name,
      id: topLevelItem.titles[0].subtitles[0].id,
      title_id: topLevelItem.titles[0].subtitles[0].title_id,
    };

    result[contentKey] = {
      id: topLevelItem.titles[0].subtitles[0].content[0].id,
      name: topLevelItem.titles[0].subtitles[0].content[0].name,
      subtitle_id: topLevelItem.titles[0].subtitles[0].content[0].subtitle_id,
    };

    return result;
  }, {});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a recursive approach by using a level and an array for the keys.

```js
const
    data = [{ titles: [{ id: 1, name: "Title 01", subtitles: [{ id: 2, name: "Subtitle 01", title_id: 1, content: [{ id: 3, name: "Content 01", subtitle_id: 2 }] }] }, { id: 4, name: "Title 01", subtitles: [{ id: 5, name: "Subtitle 01", title_id: 4, content: [{ id: 6, name: "Content 01", subtitle_id: 5 }] }] }] }],
    convert = (data, keys) => {
        const
            numbers = {},
            flat = level => ({ [keys[level]]: sub = [], ...o }) => {
                const key = keys[level - 1];
                numbers[key] ??= 0; 
                return [
                    ...(level ? [[key + (++numbers[key]).toString().padStart(2, 0), o]] : []),
                    ...sub.flatMap(flat(level + 1))
                ];
            }

        return Object.fromEntries(data.flatMap(flat(0)));
    },
    result = convert(data, ['titles', 'subtitles', 'content']);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```